# How can i prevent LaTex from converting a apostrophe combination to this weird character?

Tags: symbols, characters

I want to write this

[image: required text]

But it becomes to this in the resulting PDF file

[image]

How can i prevent LaTex from converting the apostrophe combination to this weird character?

Comment: Add a space inbetween: `" e`.

Comment: Never use `"` for quotes, but always double back quote and `''`

Comment: @Johannes_B Didn't help, the result is the same as before

Comment: Even better would be the use of package `csquotes`: `\enquote{MARA}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In case that for some unfathomable reason you  do not want the legal english or german quotation marks (egreg's  answer)  but just `"`,  you  can use `"{}` ... or better  `\textquotedbl` .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Never use `"` for quotes. In particular, if you use `babel-german`, where `"` is a shorthand character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

``DAMN'' ebenfalls

,,Damn`` ebenfalls

"`Damn"' ebenfalls

"<Damn"> ebenfalls

\end{document}
```

[image]